# Branch cuts and isolated singularties

Tags: complex-analysis

I remember reading that branch cuts can be understood as integrals of poles of infinitesimal residue. For example, the `arccot`function has a branch discontinuity from `-i` to `+i` and
$$
\frac 1 2 \int ^1_{-1} \frac 1{ z + i\ a} \operatorname d a = \operatorname {arccot}( z )
$$

Are there analytic functions with branch cuts that cannot be expressed as integrals of poles of infinitesimal residue?

Comment: $\log z$ needs a regularization term: $$\log z = \int_0^\infty (\frac1{1+x}-\frac1{z+x})dx$$ Also what do you think of the Cauchy integral formula, or did you mean not all contour integrals are allowed?

Comment: @reuns For the purposes of my question, this is the way I understand your example: Pick the real positive axis as the branch cut for the function `log`. On that path, add up the functions $z ↦ \big[(1+x)^{-1}−(z+x)^{-1}\big]\ dx$ which have poles at $x$ with residue $dx$. If you chose a different branch cut, a different subintegrand might be needed.